# Code keeps giving me m at the end of the string which is created

Tags: c, ansi-c

This code basically takes what a user puts (a-z) in and converts it into morse code. But the return string always has 'm' at the end tried to do a millions of stuff to fix it can you see what I have done wrong, thanks.

```
//Functions
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctype.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h> 
void morse(void);   //prototype
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for(;;){
    morse(); // function call
    }
}

void morse(void){

    char *ss= (char*)malloc(110); // allocating dynamic memory
    strcpy(ss, ".-  -...-.-.-.. .   ..-.--. ......  .----.- .-..--  -.  --- .--.--.-.-. ... -   ..- ...-.-- -..--.----..");
    char *pp =(char*)malloc(110);
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    printf("Enter text to convert to morse code: ");
    scanf("%s", pp);
    char *q =(char*)malloc(110);
    while (*pp != '\0'){//intiate while loop
        *pp = *(pp + n); 
        int f = (*pp - 97)*4; //find letters postion in morse code string
        int a = 0;

        while (a != 4) //copy morse code for the letter into new string
        {
            *(q + i) = *(ss + f);
            i++;
            a++;
            f++;
        }
        n++;

    }
    q[i] = '\0';    
    printf("%s", q); //return morse code
    printf("\n");
    free(ss); //free the allocated memory
    free(pp);
    free(q);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that, but `int f = (*pp - 97)*4;` is going to bite if anything but lower case letters of the Latin alphabet are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop goes around for one extra character. The outer loop looks for *pp being \0, but *pp is still the prior character's value.

Change it to:

```
while (*(pp+n) != '\0') {  // test next character
    char c = *(pp + n);    // fetch next character
    int f = (c - 97)*4;    // find character's index into morse array
```

The way I found this was to run under the debugger and watch what was going on. It soon became apparent when it went around the loop twice even though I'd entered only one character. Use the debugger, it's a great tool. It's worth stepping through code through the debugger, even if you think it's working. Sometimes you get a surprise!

Comment: which debugger is this?? I use visual studio 2010 for only a month and a bit and have not really tested most of the tools out.. thanks

Comment: VS2010 has a great debugger built in. Try it out. You'll love it, and it will save you a lot of time as well as help understand your programming better.  (I happened to use Xcode's.). Remember to mark answers as correct, you are more likely to get answers to future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Debug and check the value of "n".

You can do like this:

```
   while (*pp != '\0'){//intiate while loop
        //*pp = *(pp + n); 
        int f = (*pp - 97)*4; //find letters postion in morse code string
        int a = 0;

        while (a != 4) //copy morse code for the letter into new string
        {
            *(q + i) = *(ss + f);
            i++;
            a++;
            f++;
        }
        //n++;
        pp++;

    }
```